# How can systematic errors be calculated?

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis

Usually, it is said that systematic errors can not be handled in a well-defined way, unlike statistical errors.

My questions:

1. How can systematical errors be calculated for any experimental device or experiment? Maybe does it involve a "calibration" of experimental devices?
2. I have heard that bayesian methods provide THE tool to estimate and calculate systematic errors. How is it done?